# Does enabling CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE keep Snowflake infrastructure up constantly?

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive cause the snowflake infrastructure to always stay up? I am wondering only because of costs. We are billed based on how long the intra is up, so if queries are rarely run would it be a bad idea to use this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, in snowflake the cost is primarily for compute and storage. The compute will be charged as long as your warehouse is up. If the warehouse is suspended, you do not get charged for compute. In snowflake, it is not the queries which cost you compute money, it is based on how long your warehouse is up. My guess here is that for keeping your session alive, there is not need for warehouse and hence it will not cost you anything. But in any case, it would not be a good idea to keep a session alive for long as that is a security risk.

Comment: This is accurate.  That statement keeps your session alive, but not your warehouse.  It is also considered a security risk.

Comment: The docs say if CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE is `false`: the user must log in again after four hours of inactivity. Does this mean if there is continuous activity the session never expires?

Comment: @Mike you can see here that one of the solutions is to query periodically `select 1;`
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/218#issuecomment-544003116